# Custom image is not creating if Guest create Product Programtically

Tags: magento-1.9

Once **Registered user** upload custom image on [Product view image](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-7.html) & click on button, We are creating Product programtically with **custom image**.

but when guest click on same button after uploading custom image, Product is creating with **static** image [ Image which is present in **media/example/amasty** folder]

We want to create product with custom image for guest also....

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath="") 
{       
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->setName($originalProduct->getName()); 

        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);      

        $images = array(
            'thumbnail'   => 'image.png',           
            'image'       => 'image.png',  
        ); 

        foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
            if($newImagePath != ""){
                $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
                $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
            }else{
                $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
                $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
            }

            if (file_exists($path)) {
                try {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
            }
        }

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();

        return $product;
    }
```

full controllers : https://pastebin.com/Gn6iMwug

Comment: $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);  have you tried by commenting these 2 line ?

Comment: @MineshPatel yes, still the same.....

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the `$newImagePath` variable. May be you are not sending this value. Check that.

Comment: @KingshukDeb but for Registered users its working fine, let me cross check once.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento you mean create custom product with image programmatically ??

Comment: @Dhrumin sorry for late reply , Thanks for support..... i got solution......

Comment: @BabyinMagento can you please add an answer and accept - just to close this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );
        $res = '';
        $login = "";
        $productId = "";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }

        try {
            if (isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login != "")) {

                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                    '_secure' => true
                ));

                $result['success'] = true;
                $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();

            }

            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {


            // Registered user click on save design
            return $res = $this->saveProduct($type, $doSave, $originalProduct, $newImagePath);

            } else {
                $p_data = array(
                'type' => $type, 
                'doSave' => $doSave, 
                'newImagePath' => $newImagePath,
                'name' => $originalProduct->getName(),
                );
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsProductdata();
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setProductdata($p_data);

                $result['success'] = false;

                //guest enter wrong credentilas & click on login

                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return $this; exit;     

            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            switch ($e->getCode()) {
                case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                    $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                    break;
                case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                    break;
                default:
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $result['error'] = $message;
            $session->setUsername($login['username']);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result = "ERROR :" . $e->getMessage();


        }       

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));       
    }

public function saveProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath) {

            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            $rand = rand(11, 999999999);
            $product->setTypeId($type)
            ->setAttributeSetId(17)
            ->setSku('CDSB1_sku' . $rand)
            ->setWebsiteIDs(array(
                1
            ));                      

            $product
                ->setCategoryIds(array(2, 3))
                ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) 
            ;

            $product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 
                'manage_stock' => 0, 
                'is_in_stock' => 1,
                'qty' => 50
            ));

            $product->setIsMassupdate(true)->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);

            $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());

            $product->setDescription($originalProduct->getDescription())->setShortDescription($originalProduct->getShortDescription())

                ->setPrice(599)
                ->setTaxClassId(0)
                ->setWeight(1);
            $product->setDeliveryInfo($originalProduct->getDeliveryInfo());
            $product->setInteriorExterior($originalProduct->getInteriorExterior());
            $product->setSizeSpace($originalProduct->getSizeSpace());


            $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
            $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);
            $product->setCustomUid($customerId);

            $emaildate = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');


            if ($doSave) {          

                $images = array(

                    'image' => 'image.png' 

                );


                $imag_data = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getProductImage();
                $newImagePath = $imag_data;

                foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) 
                {
                    $path = '';
                    if ($newImagePath != "") 
                    {
                        $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
                        $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
                        $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
                    }                  

                    if (file_exists($path)) 
                    { 
                        try 
                        {                          
                           $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, array('image','thumbnail'), false);
                        } 
                        catch (Exception $e) 
                        {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
            $product->save();                       

            return $product;    
    }
```